# How to disable the whole dropdownlist in flex 4

Tags: flex4, drop-down-menu

I'm fairly new to Flex. I'm trying to disable a DropDownList in order to prevent the user from changing the selection at a certain occasion. (So, when clicking on the DropDownList it would not open.)

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the following code:

```
myDropDown.enabled = false;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I don't know why I kept looking for a disable property.